# Java/.NET mark a reference as "do not follow" for the garbage collector?

Tags: java, .net, garbage-collection, pass-by-reference

In .NET/Java you can wrap references in classes that have magic properties with respect to the garbage collector (e.g. WeakReference etc..)

There looks to be no such class for the idea of a "Do Not Follow" reference - i.e. a way to tell the garbage collector that there is a complex subgraph of objects from the specified reference onwards and that it should not be collected. (So don't waste cpu cycles doing a mark and sweep of that subgraph).

Does anyone know why this feature isn't there?

Many thanks

Comment: The objects would still need to be traversed, because they may reference other objects. Basically they would be an addition to the root set.

Comment: By marking them as "Do not follow" you'd be saying that anything they reference should be retained. And possibly that from the point the gc first observes the reference as "do not follow" it should assume the subgraph contained beneath is immutable.

Comment: The GC would need to somehow *ensure* that every reference in that graph is immutable. Otherwise referenced objects could be collected violating language and vm safety.

Comment: yes - I guess it could copy it to a separate memory area that raises an access violation when written to subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

The feature isn't there because it wouldn't do what you are thinking. A mark-and-sweep collector traverses the object graph and notes which objects should be *kept*. If you told it not to mark some subgraph, then the collector would discard all of those objects when it did whatever it did to clean up. The only useful reference statuses are "keep this" (hold a reference in the graph anchored in the main class), "throw this away" (don't hold any references reachable from there), and "you may choose whether to throw this away" (`WeakReference`).

Comment: Thanks, you're right that "do not follow" is not a good description w.r.t to the actual implementation - but I don't think this alters the overall idea. IF you rename it to be "immutable and uncollectable" then that maybe makes more sense? Whatever marking mechanism is used by the gc can be used on the first observation to mark everything permenantly from there and then leave it alone. Or copy and compact it to a distinct memory area that isn't gc'd?

Comment: A mark-and-sweep garbage collector doesn't keep any mark information from previous runs; it starts off with a completely empty set of objects to keep and adds items from there.  Even if this made sense in the context of a mark-and-sweep collector, however, the JLS wouldn't specify it, because there's no requirement concerning how the garbage collector is implemented (or even if the JVM has one).

Comment: How about the copying to a separate memory idea? Is it possible to approach the question from a trying-to-make-it-work perspective?

Comment: This isn't practical in a system with managed memory (JVM, .NET CLR). The whole point of such a system is that you don't have to explicitly deallocate memory when you're done with it, and while you could certainly have the option to "freeze" objects (Ruby and some other languages support it), trying to tell the GC that certain objects should go in a separate area and never be deallocated is asking for trouble (requires GC special-casing, risk of DOS or memory leaks...).

Comment: "requires GC special-casing" - yes by definition, this isn't a bad thing. "risk of DOS" - it could be a privileged action in the run-time, "memory leaks" - again by definition you're explicitly requesting this in a way - you're saying "I know best, don't worry about this subgraph". I don't think a technical reason has been presented against this idea yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the design of the GC is to assume everything is dead and find the *live* objects, then collect the rest. To make your idea work, you would have to invert the approach to make the GC start with everything alive and find *dead* objects.

Consider this scenario. You have an object A, that is your special "Don't navigate my graph" object. Your graph goes A->B->C. In a GC that finds live objects, it will have no way of knowing that B and C are alive, because the "Don't navigate my graph" flag will stop it from finding B and C. So A stays alive but B and C get collected. Not good.

So why does the GC searches for live objects, not dead ones? To find live objects, the GC starts at references it knows for certain are still in use (called roots). These are typically references that are on the stack (local variables in currently running methods), static references, and a few others. Every object referenced by these roots, traced recursively to the end of the graph is definitely still in use and can't be collected. Everything else is garbage.

If you implemented the inverse approach and assumed everything was alive and tried to search for dead objects, you'd have to look at every object in the heap, find out object that referenced it, and chase that graph until it runs out or you find a root. If it finds a root, everything in the chain is alive. If not, everything in the chain is dead.

The difference between the two approaches is that starting from the roots requires a lot less work. Every reference you follow is guaranteed alive. An object may be referring to a thousand other objects, but you only need to pass through it once from a root to prove that it and the thousand objects are alive. Conversely, if you never get to that object from the root, you know it's dead without ever having to navigate those thousand references.

Also, objects store what they reference, not what references them. Given an object, finding out if anyone references it would require searching all other objects' references. Or you could store a list of referees on each object, but now each reference costs twice as much memory.

In .Net, there is the GCHandle class, which allows you to create a reference which is treated as a root. Therefore the subgraph of objects will not be collected. But the subgraph must still be navigated to know what those objects are.

In short, the GC is designed this way for simplicity and performance. If you don't mark/sweep the subgraph of an object, the objects in the subgraph will potentially be garbage collected. This is the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand GC behavior is to go to a bowling alley and watch what happens after a player rolls the first ball.  The machine identifies all the pins that are still standing them, moves them off the lane, *blindly* clears the lane, and then puts the pins that were standing back on the lane.  The machine doesn't care which pins were knocked down or even how many (unless all ten pins were knocked down, in which case it will advance immediately to the next frame).  Even if one had a means of tagging pins that were knocked down, such tagging wouldn't help the pinsetter in the slightest.

Another thing to consider is that one of the most fundamental advantages of a GC framework is that there is no such thing as a dangling reference.  An objects will exist exist as long as there exists a reachable reference anywhere, and will cease to exist when the last reachable reference is destroyed.  To allow for things like weak references, the system starts by identifying all objects which can be reached via strong references.  Once that is done, the system will go through a list of weak references and invalidate any weak references whose target hasn't been marked as live.  It will also go through a list of objects which override `Finalize` and add any items which were on that list but not referenced anywhere else to a list of objects needing immediate cleanup.  An object which override `Finalize` or to which weak references exist will continue to exist until the GC obliterates any and all references that could reach it by any means; most objects, however, will cease to exist as soon as the last reference is overwritten regardless of when the GC runs to reclaim the space.